# array in php programming issue output

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 1000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => 2000
        )

)
```

I want to make the output viewable in 1 line like-
1000,2000

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $item){
    $new_array[] = $item['number'];
}
```

that should do the trick, it loops though all the arrays in the array and inputs them into a new single array.

Comment: `$item` does not look like beeing an object, try `$item['number']`

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayToString() {
    $result = '';
    foreach ( $array as $element ) {
        if ( is_array( $element ) ) {
            $result .= arrayToString( $element );
        }
        else {
            $result .= $element;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `implode()` function

```
<?php

$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated;
```

http://php.net/implode